# EntityFramework 6 in ASP.NET MVC4 Data Annotations

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

I want to get data between db.TableAs and db.TableBs using the following method:

class TableA.cs:

```
public class TableA
{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int TableBId {get;set;}
    public string description{get;set;}
    public virtual TableB TableBs{get;set;}
}
```

class TableB.cs:

```
public class TableB{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int TableAId {get;set;}
    public string description{get;set;}
    public virtual TableA TableAs{get;set;}
}
```

I have some functions that need to get TableB's data from TableA and some functions that need to get TableA's data from TableB. By doing this I am getting this error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'TableA' and 'TableB'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Can I know how do I get the data without the codes below:

```
TableB tableB = _tableBmodel.GetSingle(tableA.ID);

public TableB GetSingle(int id)
{
    return db.TableBs.Where(e => e.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: First, rename `TableBs` to `TableB` and `TableAs` to `TableA`. Second, is your relationship between tables is one-to-one?

Comment: yes...it is one-to-one...

Comment: And what table is principal and what is dependent?

Comment: An example: TableA is for classroom named A, B, C ....Then I have TableB for teacher named D, E, F...So i need to get classroom A's teacher...another way i need to get classroom for Teacher D...

Comment: It is exactly, what is needed.

Comment: any solution for this??